# Work with Unions and hexa in C++

Tags: c++

I have the following program about `Union`. I haven't really worked with many but from what i understood elements of a `Union` share the same memory space. Furthermore when i first looked at my teacher slides i thought it's was something `similar` **in a way** like `structs` but no. Anyway so i attempted to print on of a `Union` value but i don't understand it. Can someone tells me why it only prints `1` and ignore the first 5 characters? second question; 
is there a way to compute `a ^= b;` without converting `a` and `b` in binary? it's a question from a midterm practice and i thought there could be a faster way to solve since it's a `C++` course and not a digital system course.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

union Combi {
 int i;
 short s;
};


int main()
{
 unsigned int a = 0xFF, b= 0x0F0F;
a ^= b;

 Combi c;
c.i = 0xFF0001;
std::cout << c.s<<" "<<a;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A union is a data structure where [the data can be viewed different ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type#C.2FC.2B.2B). The compiler gives enough memory to `c` to store its *longest* entry. When you assign `0xFF0001` to `c.i`, that also assigns `c.s`, because they overlap. When you tell it to print `c.s`, it prints the memory, but assumes you only want to see a `short`. That's why you see only `1` and not the other characters.

> second question; is there a way to compute `a ^= b`; without converting `a` and `b` in binary?

Yes; in fact, that's what the program does (that's **hexadecimal** format, not binary). Just assign the corresponding decimal values, if you like, and `a ^= b` will work exactly the same way. Writing it in binary or hexademical format just makes it easier to read.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry im not really familiar using `bitwise` with `decimal`. Could you please provide an example with a brief explanation? like i see that `F^F` is `0`, i thought the result would be `F`, just like `1^1` gives `1`.

Comment: Since `^` is the bitwise xor operator, `F^F==0` is correct. Likewise, `1^1==0` is what you should get, and it's what my system actually gives (OS X Yosemite w/clang). If your system gives `1^1==1` that's an error. Likewise `15^15==0` and `15^7==8`, both correct and not using binary notation. The bitwise and operator is `&` and the bitwise or operator is `|`.

Comment: In symbolic logic, `and` is represented as a wedge, much like `^`. I'll bet that's the reason you assumed that. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I believe short holds less bits than required to show the FF. Think of it like a `0xffff` mask, which thus hides all bits higher than that.

Edit: Ok, in more depth, the int and short share the same location in memory. But when you specify the format, you'll get the memory data in that format (in memory, it's just a bunch of bits anyway).

So the whole Union takes up only the size of the biggest component; the int in this case.

Pretend it starts at 0x00000000.

You then set the int (the whole memory segment) to 0xFF0001.

Now it looks like 0x00FF0001.

Now you want to print out the data as a short, but a short normally only looks like 0x0000. So in this case we ignore the top half 0x00FF, and our short is the remaining part: 0x0001.

Hence you get the output of 1.